# Fetch as Google redirected to wrong URL

Tags: redirect, seo, google-search-console, googlebot

Not sure how Fetch as Google will redirected this url https://www.tonergreen.com.my/HP-CF213A-131A-Magenta-Printer-Toner-Cartridge-Value-Pack-2X to wrong URL. Im using Opencart with custom theme, how to fix this? I worry this will affected page seo ranking.

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that Googlebot is seeing the same behavior that I do as a visitor.

You tried to fetch as Googlebot the `http` version (not the `https`) version of the page.  When I do the same with curl, your server redirects me to `index.php` on the https site.

```
curl --head  http://www.tonergreen.com.my/HP-CF213A-131A-Magenta-Printer-Toner-Cartridge-Value-Pack-2X 
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://www.tonergreen.com.my/index.php?_route_=HP-CF213A-131A-Magenta-Printer-Toner-Cartridge-Value-Pack-2X
```

When I fetch the https page I get the standard 200 OK response:

```
curl --head  https://www.tonergreen.com.my/HP-CF213A-131A-Magenta-Printer-Toner-Cartridge-Value-Pack-2X 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Your server is mis-configured, it isn't Google's fault.

Comment: thanks, now i should fetch `https` version instead `http`

Comment: Testing the https version with "fetch as Google" should work fine.  You should fix your http to https redirect to redirect to the canonical version of the URL.

Answer (score 1):

The Fetch as Googlebot tool is not making a mistake.

Your question is asked different from what you are trying to do. Eg you are actually trying to view:

> http://www.tonergreen.com.my/HP-CF213A-131A-Magenta-Printer-Toner-Cartridge-Value-Pack-2X

You are trying to view a **non-https** page, and are being redirected to **https**.

This is unlikely to be anything to do with the theme.

More likely it will be due to something related to your ecommerce software, or some kind of http to https redirection you have.

Comment: but i already force browser to use https in htaccess

Comment: Great, then that explains why you are being redirected - I would look there to try and understand what is going wrong.